# Reading values from a file in c

Tags: c, file, fread

I have two files to be read. One of them contains two columns like:

```
Account Number      Amount
100                 27.14
300                 62.11
400                 100.56
900                 82.17
```

And the other file has 5 columns with the content below:

```
Account Number      Name           Surname        Balance        
100                 Alan           Jones          348.17
300                 Mary           Smith          27.19
500                 Sam            Sharp          0.00
700                 Suzy           Green          -14.22
```

I want to compare the account numbers of the two files, and add the balance of the first file to the balance of the second file. So far, I tried to get the account numbers from the first file and print it on the screen. I tried using `fread` function but it did not work.

My try is:

```
struct clientData{
    unsigned int acctNum;
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    double balance;
};
int main(){

FILE *fPtr, *fPtr2;
    
    if(!(fPtr = fopen("transaction_file.txt", "r"))){
        printf("[ERROR] File could not be found!\n");
        return;
    }
    fseek(fPtr, (0) * sizeof(struct clientData), SEEK_SET);
    
    struct clientData client = {0, "", "", 0.0};
    
    //read record from file
    fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, fPtr);
    printf("%-6u%10.2lf\n\n", client.acctNum, client.balance);
}
```

Comment: The info is probably stored as plain text, so you can't `fread` directly to `client`, you'll have to parse input first.

Comment: Those "_5 columns_" look a lot like _four_ columns to me.

Comment: They are text files, so read each line with `fgets()` then extract the information, perhaps with `sscanf()` or with `strtok()` and so on.

Comment: To "add the balance of the first file to the balance of the second file" you will need to create a new file with all the data and revised balances.

Comment: i'm not sure if it really works: fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, fPtr); -> how do you know that fread puts data exactly into field of clientData structure? Did you check it with gdb? In my opinion you shall first parse data, or at least know on which offest data of balance in file is placed. Then you can read line into the buffer and copy balance from fixed position into other buffer, or even convert (atoi, scanf), etc

Comment: @JosiP I saw a solved exampled the book 'C How to Program' and author used fread as you mentioned and it works very well. I was also surprised when I saw it at first.
And thx for other for their valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253007/2410359), but with a stronger parsing test.

```
// if (2 == sscanf(line, "%d %f", &n.number, &n.balance) ||
//     4 == sscanf(line, "%d %31s %31s %f", &n.number, n.name, n.surname, &n.balance)

int end = 0;
sscanf(line, "%d %f %n", &n.number, &n.balance, &end);
if (end > 0 && line[end] == 0) {
  ; // Handle file 1 type line
} else {
  end = 0;
  sscanf(line, "%d %31s %31s %f %n", &n.number, n.name, n.surname, &n.balance, &end);
  if (end > 0 && line[end] == 0) {
    ; // Handle file 2 type line
  }
}
```

Comment: Can the statement ` sscanf(line, "%d %31s %31s %f %n", &n.number, n.name, n.surname, &n.balance, &end);` handle table header? I have just found another solution but it cannot pass the header?
And what does `%n` do?

Comment: @akoluacik 1) What do you want to happen when the line of _table header_ is parsed.  I'd expect you would want that line to be neither a file 1 nor file 2 line.  That is what the above code does. 2) "found another solution but it cannot pass the header?" --> unclear what the _other_ solution is so no further comment on it.  `"%n"` directs `sscanf()` to save the current character offset of the scan.  For more details on that, refer to your library documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input.  Although it is totally unsuitable for production work (it is difficult if not impossible to robustly avoid undefined behavior on unexpected input), a simple way to do that is with `scanf`.
You'll want to use a data structure that make lookups easy.  The simplest (IMO) to implement is an unbalanced tree.  Something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void * xmalloc(size_t s);
FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
int die(const char *fmt, ... );

struct account {
    int number;
    float balance;
    char name[32];
    char surname[32];
    struct account *next[2];
};

void
insert(struct account **root, const struct account *n)
{
    struct account *r = *root;

    if( r == NULL ){
        r = *root = xmalloc(sizeof **root);
        memcpy(r, n, sizeof *n);
    } else if( n->number == r->number ){
        r->balance += n->balance;
        if( *r->name == '\0' ){
            strcpy(r->name, n->name);
            strcpy(r->surname, n->surname);
        }
    } else {
        insert(r->next + (n->number > r->number), n);
    }
}

const char *hdr[2] = {
    "Account Number      Amount\n",
    "Account Number      Name           Surname        Balance\n"
};
void
read_file(struct account **root, FILE *ifp)
{
    size_t cap = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    struct account n = {0};
    while( getline(&line, &cap, ifp) > 1 ){
        if( 2 == sscanf(line, "%d %f", &n.number, &n.balance) \
        || 4 == sscanf(line, "%d %31s %31s %f",
            &n.number, n.name, n.surname, &n.balance)
        ) {
            insert(root, &n);
        } else if( strcmp(line, hdr[0]) && strcmp(line, hdr[1]) ) {
            die("invalid input: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
    free(line);
}

void
print(struct account *r)
{
    if( r ){
        print(r->next[0]);
        printf("%d %-31s %-31s %.2f\n",
            r->number, r->name, r->surname, r->balance
        );
        print(r->next[1]);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct account *root = NULL;
    if( argc > 1 ){
        FILE *fp;
        for(char *const* path = argv + 1; *path; path += 1 ){
            read_file(&root, fp = xfopen(*path, "r"));
            if( fclose(fp) ){
                perror(*path);
            }
        }
    } else {
        read_file(&root, stdin);
    }
    print(root);
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
        *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}

void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
    void *rv = malloc(s);
    if( rv == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return rv;
}

int
die(const char *fmt, ... )
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```